# If $(x,y)\mapsto f(x,y)=(x-y,x-y).$ Prove that $f \circ f=0$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have proved that the following map is linear but cannot prove that $f \circ f=0$.
Here is the question:

> > Let $$f:\Bbb{R^2}\to \Bbb{R^2}$$
> >
> > $$(x,y)\mapsto f(x,y)=(x-y,x-y).$$
> >
> > Prove that $f \circ f=0$

I don't know if anyone can help me with its proof. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Formally $f\circ f$ must be proved to be the constant function $\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$ sending each element of $\mathbb R^2$ to $\langle 0,0\rangle$ (not $0$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $a=x-y$. Then

$(f \circ f)(x,y)=f(a,a)=(a-a,a-a)=(0,0)$.

Answer (score 4):

$$\langle x,y\rangle\stackrel{f}{\mapsto}\langle x-y,x-y\rangle\stackrel{f}{\mapsto}\langle (x-y)-(x-y),(x-y)-(x-y)\rangle=\langle 0,0\rangle$$

Answer (score 1):

As $f$ is a linear map, you can also look at the matrix representing $f$:

$$ A_f= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix} $$

Computing $A^2$ yields $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$. Now use the fact that this matrix represents $f \circ f$.